# Is it possible to run parallel applications (High Performance Computing) on google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, hpc

Has anyone used Google App Engine with a HPC application? is it possible to do parallelism? You can do parallelism (at least in theory) using java + threads, but how many threads can you get? how efficient is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Google App Engine, your program doesn't run in a complete JRE, but in a [sandbox](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Sandbox), which does not enable you to create new threads. Therefore, you can't just use java + threads.

But you can run some concurrent [Backends](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview.html), which are some instances "designed for applications that need faster performance, large amounts of addressable memory, and continuous or long-running background processes". These backends can be [configured](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/config/backends.html) and are [billable](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/billing.html).

Comment: note - i've edited the question to refer to app engine instead of google apps.

Answer (score 0):

App Engine is designed primarily with serving scalable web applications in mind. While you could do HPC on it, it's not its design goal, so your experience is likely to be less than satisfactory.